# Getting strings from QVariantList

Tags: c++, qt

Data from my DB is in a QVariantList and I want to loop through it and get firstname out.

```
QVariantList sqlData = database->loadDatabase("quotes.db", "quotes");
for (int i = 1; i <= sqlData.size(); i++)
    {
        qDebug() << sqlData.value(i);
    }
```

This produces:

```
Debug: QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("firstname", QVariant(QString, "Glenford") ) ( "id" ,  QVariant(qlonglong, 2) ) ( "lastname" ,  QVariant(QString, "Myers") ) ( "quote" ,  QVariant(QString, "We try to solve the problem by rushing through the design process so that enough time will be left at the end of the project to uncover errors that were made because we rushed through the design process.") ) )  )
```

How can I just debug the value of "firstname"? Eg debug = Glenford.

Thanks

Comment: Try http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#value

Comment: That doesnt help, how can I target first name?

Comment: Looking at Qt Docs I think that `sqlData.value (i).toMap().value ("firstname");` might work for you.

Comment: That produces: QVariant(QString, "Glenford") Do you know how to just output Glenford?

Comment: Try `value<QString>` on `QVariant(QString, "Glenford")` and please look at the docs for relatively simple problems like this.

Answer (score 5):

QVariant list is a list of QVariants, the object has a specific iterator for it.

```
QVariantList sqlData = database->loadDatabase("quotes.db", "quotes");
for (QVariantList::iterator j = sqlData.begin(); j != sqlData.end(); j++)
{
    qDebug() << "iterating through QVariantList ";
    qDebug() << (*j).toString(); // Print QVariant
}
```